# Why does slice capacity with odd numbers differ from behavior with even numbers

Tags: go, slice

I noticed that the capacity of slices behaves in a different way, when the capacity is an odd number. More specifically: When an element is added to a slice, the capacity of the slice is *doubled* when the original capacity was an even number. But when the original capacity was an odd number, the capacity is *incremented by one and then doubled*. Example:

```
s := make([]int, 28, 28)
s = append(s, 1) 
fmt.Println("len=", len(s), " cap=", cap(s)) // len = len + 1, cap = 2 * cap


pri := make([]int, 27, 27)
pri = append(pri, 1)
fmt.Println("len=", len(pri), " cap=", cap(pri)) // len = len + 1, cap = 2 * (cap + 1)
```

Assuming this is not a bug, what's the reason for this behavior?

Link to playground: http://play.golang.org/p/wfmdobgCUF

Comment: It can't be a bug since no where in the spec or documentation does it make any mention whatsoever what the new capacity will be. Any specific Go implementation/runtime is free to allocate as small or as large of a new underlying array as it wants to.

Comment: Exactly, [`runtime.growslice`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/32fddadd98f938018485fba6253d30273db4e5e9/src/runtime/slice.go#L51) grows the slice's underlying array to be _at least_ as big as the capacity parameter. Still, the question is interesting.

Comment: There is no proof it's always like this. Did you check for 29?

Comment: This "double-ing" theory doesn't stand if capacity is "big". Try with initial `2800` instead of `28`, new capacity will be `3520` instead of `5600`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Short answer

It is rounding up the slice capacity to fill the allocated memory blocks.

### Long answer

Let's have a look into the Go1.5.1 source code  :

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f2e4c8b5fb3660d793b2c545ef207153db0a34b1/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/walk.go#L2895 tells us that `append(l1, l2...)` is expanded to

```
s := l1
if n := len(l1) + len(l2) - cap(s); n > 0 {
    s = growslice_n(s, n)
}
s = s[:len(l1)+len(l2)]
memmove(&s[len(l1)], &l2[0], len(l2)*sizeof(T))
```

The part we are interested in, `growslice_n`, is defined there : https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f2e4c8b5fb3660d793b2c545ef207153db0a34b1/src/runtime/slice.go#L36

Going a bit deeper, we find this :

```
newcap := old.cap
if newcap+newcap < cap {
    newcap = cap
} else {
    for {
        if old.len < 1024 {
            newcap += newcap
        } else {
            newcap += newcap / 4
        }
        if newcap >= cap {
            break
        }
    }
}

/* [...] */

capmem := roundupsize(uintptr(newcap) * uintptr(et.size))
newcap = int(capmem / uintptr(et.size))
```

`roundupsize` is defined there : https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f2e4c8b5fb3660d793b2c545ef207153db0a34b1/src/runtime/msize.go#L178

```
// Returns size of the memory block that mallocgc will allocate if you ask for the size.
func roundupsize(size uintptr) uintptr {
    if size < _MaxSmallSize {
        if size <= 1024-8 {
            return uintptr(class_to_size[size_to_class8[(size+7)>>3]])
        } else {
            return uintptr(class_to_size[size_to_class128[(size-1024+127)>>7]])
        }
    }
    if size+_PageSize < size {
        return size
    }
    return round(size, _PageSize)
}
```

And it was introduced there : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-codereviews/bFGtI4Cpb_M

> When growing slice take into account size of the allocated memory block.